# Why does the destroy signal not reach the children of a Gtk.ScrolledWindow?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

Please consider this python code for a simple GTK window:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

def on_destroy(widget):
    print("Destroying {}".format(widget))

def on_click(button, scroll):
    scroll.destroy()

scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scroll.connect("destroy", on_destroy)

button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Self-destruct")
scroll.add(button)
button.connect("destroy", on_destroy)
button.connect("clicked", on_click, scroll)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.add(scroll)
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.set_size_request(200, 75)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

When pressing the button, I would expect to get two output lines reporting that the ScrolledWindow and the button got destroyed. In reality I only get one line reporting about the ScrolledWindow, the destroy signal never reaches the button. If I replace the ScrolledWindow with a normal Box, the destroy signal reaches the button. Why is this?

Comment: Your request seems weird, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @theGtknerd In a project with images inside a scrolled window that gets destroyed and created multiple times I noticed that the memory of the images does not get garbage collected upon destruction of the window. When I call destroy manually on the images' container, the memory is freed. I don't understand why I would have to call destroy manually.

Comment: This is interesting to know, I have wondered about things like this myself. Back to work...

Comment: @Sesshu: what tool do you use to see images are not "garbage collected"? There's no garbage collector in GTK+, all is reference-counted. Furthermore, calling `gtk_main_quit()` exists the program so the OS should reclaim all ressources. Unless they are still owned by the X server or something?

Comment: @liberforce I just look at the memory usage of the process. With "getting garbage collected" I mean that the process stays at roughly the same usage instead of constantly increasing for every created (and destroyed) window.

Comment: @Sesshu: There are lots of tools to check for memory usage, and each number mean different things. Please share your exact method. Do you use a GUI for that ? The RSS numbers for the process in the output of the `ps` command? Something else?

Comment: @liberforce I use gnome-system-monitor's memory column but top's or ps' RES column also work fine.

Comment: @Sesshu: In fact I tested your code and I do have two logs, one for each widget: ` 
Destroying <ScrolledWindow object at 0x7fe276e80f30 (GtkScrolledWindow at 0x179f180)>
Destroying <Button object at 0x7fe276af8828 (GtkButton at 0x17a41c0)>`. What version of GTK+ are you using, and on which OS?

Comment: @liberforce I'm using gtk 3.24.1 on ArchLinux. Also tested it with 3.22.30.

Comment: @Sesshu: works for me with 3.10.8 with Ubuntu Trusty.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't tell you much more than this code which does delete the button. Hopefully, you can adapt it to your needs. It does seem like the button unattaches itself from the Viewport and attaches itself to nothing, because the button's destroy handler runs on app shutdown, and causes weird errors. It would be interesting to post this on the Gtk mailing list for any other thoughts.

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

def on_destroy(widget, viewport):
    print("Destroying {}".format(widget))
    viewport.get_child().destroy()

def on_button_destroy(widget):
    print("Destroying button {}".format(widget))

def on_click(button):
    scroll = button.get_parent().get_parent()
    scroll.destroy()

scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Self-destruct")
scroll.add(button)
viewport = button.get_parent()
button.connect("destroy", on_button_destroy)
scroll.connect("destroy", on_destroy, viewport)
button.connect("clicked", on_click)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.add(scroll)
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.set_size_request(200, 75)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```